# Unexpected change in Field's `DataType` when adding custom `Binding` to postgres-enum-typed `TableField`

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

We're using JOOQ 3.7.3 with Postgres 9.5. We make use of Postgres' `enum` types and map them to our own (hand-written) Java enums. The JOOQ metamodel so far looks like this:

```java
TableField<InvoiceAccountingEntryRecord, AccountingTypeEnum> ACCOUNTING_TYPE = 
     createField("accounting_type",
                 org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(com.us.app.schema.enums.AccountingTypeEnum.class),                                                                                                       
                 this,  
                 "");
```

Using JOOQ-generated enums made Schema-generation easy, but we needed a lot of explicit mapping. We'd like to use our own enum types in the JOOQ model directly, and define a custom binding for each one in the JOOQ generator config:

```xml
<customType>
  <name>AccountingTypeEnum</name>
  <type>com.us.own.enums.AccountingType</type>
  <binding>com.us.own.enums.AccountingType.AccountingTypeJooqBinding</binding>
</customType>
...
<forcedType>
  <name>AccountingTypeEnum</name>
  <expression>.*ACCOUNTING_TYPE</expression>
</forcedType>
```

Strangely enough, this not only affects the Field's value type, but also the `DataType`, which is changed to `DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("USER-DEFINED")`, a `DataType<Object>` :

```java
TableField<InvoiceAccountingEntryRecord, AccountingType> ACCOUNTING_TYPE = 
     createField("accounting_type",
                 org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("USER-DEFINED"),
                 this,
                 "",
                 new AccountingTypeJooqBinding());
```

Why is this, and can I make sure I get the `DataType<AccountingTypeEnum>` it used before?

Comment: Just to be sure: Can you reproduce this with 3.10.2? Also, does this effect only depend on your `<forcedType/>` match? Not perhaps on the fact that this enum is not generated at all, either because it is in an excluded schema, or because you turned off enum generation?

Comment: @LukasEder: Thanks for the fast response. Regarding the version I'll have to get back to you. I'm sure that the `forcedType` expression is the only trigger, because I have tables in the same schema with/without the `USER-DEFINED` type whenever the expression is not general enough...

Comment: OK, I'll try reproducing this. Probably a bug. Another thing you could try is this: Does it also happen with `Converter` instead of `Binding`? Or, in other words, what's the reason you prefer using a binding here, if you want to rely on the jOOQ-generated enum type?

Comment: Using Converters doesn't change the `USER-DEFINED` effect. I am using binding because given the `USER-DEFINED` DataType, Postgres rejects INSERTs because they lack the necessary cast `::accounting_type`.

Comment: This does appear to be a bug, but I cannot seem to reproduce it right away, neither with jOOQ 3.11.0-SNAPSHOT nor 3.10.2. Is the enum in the same schema as the table? Are both objects included in your code generation? Could you produce an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help me reproduce this?

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for your efforts. The enums are defined in the same schema as the tables that use them. I'll try to reproduce this in a minimal setting over the holidays and get back to you through JOOQ's issue tracker on github.

Comment: @LukasEder: just FYI: I can reproduce the bug in JOOQ 3.7.3 but it's obviously fixed in 3.10.3.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is upgrading or working around this by manually declaring the type in the generated class (e.g., you could run a post processor after code generation) an option for you?

Comment: @LukasEder: You're too kind... we've already found a workaround, and will hopefully upgrade soon anyway. All is well, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments, it turns out that this is indeed a bug in JOOQ's generator, which affects 3.7.3 but is no longer present in 3.10.3. Time to upgrade!

Comment: The fix may be related to [this JOOQ issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6367).